# Page navigation (within a page) based on anchor tags without browser history (or #anchor appended to url)

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have a long page and use a menu to navigate to different parts of it using the anchor tag.
This, however, is recorded in the browser history. So going 'back' will only move you within the page, not go back to the previous 'real' page.

How can I use this and not record in the browser history - maybe using jQuery or similar, or maybe even without updating the URL with the #anchor tag itself?

I'm coding in HTML5.

---

Here is the menu code:

```
<div class="entry_jump_menu clearfix">
 <ul class="basic_menu">
  <li><a href="entry_about" class="entry_page_anchor_menu menu_about">About</a></li>
  ....
 </ul> 
</div>
```

and the anchor:

```
 <div id="entry_about ...>
  ... some content ...
 </div>
```

I couldn't get the code below to work at all so I used this instead.

```
/**
 * ANCHOR TAGS WITHOUT HISTORY
 */   
$('.entry_page_anchor_menu').click(function(){
    var jump = $(this).attr('href');
    var new_position = $('#'+jump).offset();
    window.scrollTo(new_position.left,new_position.top);
    return false;
});
```

Many thanks to David for his efforts. A shame I couldn't get it to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, your jQuery seems workable to me. With some small modifications I created this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.entry_page_anchor_menu').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var jump = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        var new_position = $('#'+jump).offset();
        window.scrollTo(new_position.left,new_position.top);
    });
});
```

It allows you to use standard anchor bookmarks (#whatever) which will degrade nicely. I put the code up for you in a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tbag/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That code will be better since it degrades and I can use the usual hash tagged anchor href links for non-javascript browsers. In case you were confused, user David posted an answer to my original query and helped a lot, but I just couldn't get his code to work, so in my above edit the 'code below' wasn't refering to the code i posted, but to the now removed answer posted by David. For credit, I got the above code from here: http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/javascript/javascript-jump-to-anchor-or-element-using-jquery/